# Assigning multiple values to an integer in VB

Tags: vb.net

I have declared a variable as an integer. I want it to start from 1 and not exceed 6. Is there a simple way to do that?

```
  Dim IntNum as Interger = 1-6
```

I tried that but it didnt work

Comment: A single `integer` variable can only hold a single value, not a range of values. You may need a `List<Integer>` instead, that can hold multiple integers.

Comment: What are you trying to do? A variable doesn't work like that. A variable of type integer can only hold one integer. I believe you are looking for an "Array" which is a type of variable that can hold many values.

Comment: @xxbbcc I have a button which keeps on adding 1 to this value but i dont want it to exceed 6 even if the button is pressed more than 6 times.

Comment: @thearrow then you need to not add 1 if the value is already 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you seem to want to restrict the lower and upper bound of a single `Integer` - that is, you want to make sure that a single value is no less than `X` and is no greater than `Y`. In this case, simply use an `If` statement to avoid changing the value if the value would go outside the range.

```
Dim IntNum as Interger = 1

...

' Inside the button's click handler: only increment IntNum
' if it's less than 6.
If IntNum < 6 Then
    IntNum = IntNum + 1
End If

...
```

Note, that I didn't add code to check if `IntNum` is less than `1` - if you're only adding `1` to `IntNum` it cannot possibly become less than `1`, so there's no need to check. If you later add a button to decrement `IntNum`, you'll have to have a similar check in that button's handler to make sure you don't go below `1`.

Your question is very vague so I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Edit*

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim counterMax As Integer = 6
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Not counter = counterMax Then counter += 1
        MsgBox(counter)
    End Sub
End Class
```